# Time point to string

Tags: smart-contract, dapp

I am currently trying to get the current time using `time_point_sec(now());` Does someone know how to convert that to a `std::string`?

Comment: Can you please tell me the use case if possible?

Comment: @NirdeshKumarChoudhary - Am busy with a voting system and needed something to add entropy to my hashes so that they are unique.